# match data then insert/update in PL/SQL

Tags: oracle, plsql, oracle11g

I need the best approach in PL/SQL for this scenario:

We get the feed from an external system and data is loaded into the staging table (truncate before load). The data from staging table has to be compared (10 key columns) with target table. The target table has operational_flag column which stores values as ‘I-INACTIVE’, ‘A-ACTIVE’

On comparing staging table and target table (only ‘A-ACTIVE’ records), If data is same for the key columns, do not do anything.

If any of the key column data differs, UPDATE the target table with operational_flag = ‘I-INACTIVE’, then INSERT new row in target table with values from staging table with operational_flag = ‘A-ACTIVE’

How to do this in PL/SQL in an efficient manner?

Comment: This is not a common business scenario. In a common business scenario, you would have a TIMESTAMP instead of your `OPERATIONAL_FLAG`. Then you wouldn't need to update anything in existing rows in the target table when they become "stale" or "inactive". And the problem would have a trivial solution with the `MERGE` statement.

Comment: Ok, let's say it's not a common business scenario.  I have the requirement that needs to be accomplished the way I stated here.  Could you help?

Comment: Does your target table have a primary key? You talk about ~ 10 "key columns" but how do you identify which row in the update (staging table) is supposed to correspond to which row in the target table?

Comment: Or.. actually not a primary key; but rather a column (or group of columns) that is/are a "primary key" for the sub-table of active rows only.

Comment: Consider 10 key columns as group of columns as unique combination

Comment: That doesn't make sense. How do you recognize which row in the external data must be matched to which row in the target table? If the value in the fifth column changed, matching by ALL TEN columns will fail. The PK must be a subset of the columns (or perhaps other columns, not included in your ten "key" columns) that will be EXACTLY THE SAME between the external data and the target (for a give row).

Comment: AJ, what you're stating doesn't make sense. Here is the contradiction - "if data is same for the key columns ( about 10 key columns )"..."If any of the key column data differs, UPDATE the target table with operational_flag = ‘I-INACTIVE’"

So if everything matches we do nothing... but if some of the "key column data" is different, how do we know which rows to set to inactive?

The real solution would be to figure out what your real primary keys are and make a composite primary key, or clean up your data.

Comment: This is pretty much what `MERGE` is for. But if you want a usable answer [edit] your question and the table definitions (as `create table` statements) add some sample data and the expected output based on that data. [**Formatted text**](http://stackoverflow.com/help/formatting) please, [no screen shots](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-may-i-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557). [Edit] your question, do **not** post code or additional information in comments

Comment: Unfortunately bi-temporarility or inline versioning like this pretty much defeats `merge` (along with integrity constraints and efficient access). There are ways of doing it in a single pass but they involve duplicating the staging data using an inline view or `with` clause and I'm not sure it's worth it.